# PHP script works not everywhere

Tags: php

I've been working on a newsscript, that displays all the newsitems on a page (a sort of archive). On that page I can drag an item below/above another item and saves the order in my database. This works fine on my test server, but now is my website ready and I transferred all my files to another server and the script won't work anymore. The PHP-version of my testserver is: 5.3.18, and the other one is: 5.2.11. Maybe this is the problem, or not?

Comment: PHP 3.x is over ten years old. Why are you still using it? Actually, does a PHP 3.5.x even exist?

Comment: Ah no no, my testserver is version 5.3.18 and the other one is 5.2.11.

Comment: This is no phpmyadmin issue, but just a php one. And please specify 'won't work anymore', that ain't no fault description. The version can be a reason.

Comment: Please tell us more about the error. (if you have no error message, turn error reporting on or look in the server logs). There are things that have changed between 5.2 and 5.3, which may be causing the problem, but it could also be differences in the config between your old installation and the new one. We really can't help without knowing more about the problem.

Comment: Also, I suggest upgrading the PHP 5.2 server. 5.2 was declared End Of Life several years ago now; it is obsolete and insecure, and should not be in use any more. The minimum version you should consider using is 5.3, and even that is starting to get old (5.4 has been out for a year, and 5.5 is due to be released in a month or two). If you're on a web host that won't upgrade past 5.2, you should consider switching hosts: no good web admin would allow unsupported and insecure software to remain on their servers, so if they're on 5.2 and won't upgrade, they're obviously not a good provider.

Answer (score 2):

Information is available on [PHP 5.2 to 5.3 changes](http://php.net/manual/en/migration53.changes.php).  You should note that there are a small number of [incompatibilities](http://php.net/manual/en/migration53.incompatible.php) (i.e. valid 5.2 items that fail on 5.3) and various [new features](http://php.net/manual/en/migration53.new-features.php) (i.e. requiring 5.3 over 5.2).  You may well have code that requires 5.3 to function and may need to rewrite your code to get it to function on 5.2.